# Looking for a swing (or other) text editor component that has document selectors

Tags: java, user-interface, swing

I am creating a java app that needs to display multiple documents worth of plain text. I have been playing around with JEditorPane (for each document to display text) with JTabbedPane (for document selection) but I think I would prefer to use something better (if it exists).

Is there an existing class that creates a dead simple editor with document selector functionality built in?

Comment: I believe that there is no such component. Or maybe you meant "several documents one after another"?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is built-in to do this, but JDesktopPane might be a better option for selection rather than a JTabbedPane.

Answer (score 0):

For plain text, I would tend to prefer [`JTextArea`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html) "that displays multiple lines of text and optionally allows the user to edit the text." It is described in the article [*How to Use Text Areas*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html). The `append()` method is particularly convenient. The articles [*Text Area Scrolling*](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/22/text-area-scrolling/) and [*Message Console*](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/08/message-console/) are also very helpful.